# Need an equation to measure frequency of a certain period over days, months, years.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, time-series

Example)  Curious as to how many times a certain song of 3:46 will repeat over a given amount of time. How many times over a day, month, year, and the remaining growing fraction of time left over.

Answer (score 1):

Just express a (standard) day, month, and year in seconds.  Then divide those by $226$ seconds.

A decent expression for a day is $86400$ seconds.  A month is $30$ days (more or less) and a year is $365$ days (more or less).

Leap seconds aside, the song will start playing again at the same time every $113$ days (since the least common multiple of $86400$ and $226$ is $113 \times 86400$).  Every year that is divisible by $4$, except those years that are divisible by $100$ but not $400$ are leap years.  This lets you predict the exact times that the song will start to play again for hundreds of years if you play it continuously.

The song will play completely $381$ or $382$ times a day.  There is an extra $68$ seconds each day: $$86400 \text{ mod } 226 \equiv 68 \text{ mod }226,$$ so depending on when the song starts you may lose a full play of the song.

Also interesting is that $86400/226 = 282.30088...$ -- that is, it's *almost* $282.3$ but not quite, so the times *almost* repeat every $10$ days.  But not quite.  That could be, um, annoying to your character.

Comment: Yeah but there's a remainder of the song left over in a day's time or an hour's time. I'm searching for an equation that will take into account this remainder.

Comment: A decreasing amount that will eventually hit zero. For every new hour the song will be off by a value of .0707965 on its repeat cycle. Changing the frequency of it by day... make sense or no?

Comment: What do you need?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm writing something in which a character listens to the same song all day every day. Eventually it drives him mad. I'm looking for the proper math behind how each new day will change. Whether the song is heard at 3:00 or 3:15 the next day. You know? I think this is closer to a statistics equation

Comment: Added information.

Comment: Added a bit more.

Comment: As John says, each day is 86400 seconds.  If the song is 226 seconds, he will hear it 382 or 383 times, as $382 \lt  86400/226 \lt 383$  The next day is will repeat 68 seconds later as that is the remainder on dividing 86400/226.  If the first play on day 1 is at midnight, the first play on day 2 will start at 12:01:08, the first play on day 3 will start at 12:02:16 but the first play on day 4 jumps back

Comment: These are the numbers I was coming up with as well. It's rather confusing after a while and was hoping there'd be some easier way at figuring this out through one equation. Thank you so much for the feedback. This really helps me, a lot. Please add more if there are other conclusions that you both come to. Thank you again

Comment: If you want one equation, you should ask a clear question.  A floor function will get you one equation for many of the questions that might be what you are asking.  "If you don't know what you want your program to do, you shouldn't be writing it yet"-attributed to Bill Gates